# I have been trying to use something like: input[type=text] into my css but it isn't working

Tags: html, css, forms, input, styling

I have included a jfiddle below.  I tried setting my css code to input[type=text] so that the styling wouln't affect the submit and reset button, but something is wrong and I'm not sure what.

http://jsfiddle.net/SYcP2/

```
<link css="" href="common/css/complianceCSS.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link css="" href="../privacy/internal/css/turquoise.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <h1 class="allpages">Questions or Concerns about Compliance Issues?</h1>
   <h3>We welcome all compliments and constructive criticism!</h3>

    <form class="webform" action="http://hsc.unm.edu/scripts/cfmailform/cfmailer.cfm" method="post">
    <!--Required hidden operators--> 
    <input name="recipient" type="hidden" value="bfloran@salud.unm.edu" />
    <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="HSC Compliance Office Email Form" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cc" value="mgwilson@salud.unm.edu" />

    <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://hsc.unm.edu/admin/compliance/ThankYOU.html" /> <!-- Field validation for the user -->
```

```
  <label for "name">Your Name (optional):</label>

  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" /><br />
  <label for "name">Your E-mail (Optional):</label>
  <input name="mail" type="text" value="" /><br>
  <label for "name">Comment:</label>
  <textarea name="comment" value="" ></textarea>
  <p>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

  </form>
```

Comment: cant see anything such in your fiddle. Also there is too much html in your fiddle and its hard to know

Comment: "Something is wrong" is not a usable description of any kind of problem. You should clearly state what happens and what it is you expected to happen. The JSFiddle link is nice to put it, but it should *complement* the question's text.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say was that I don't want the submit and reset buttons the same size as the input fields.  I tried to do something like input[type=text] so that only the text was affected and not the input submit or input reset but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to apply the css to only the input type:text and not the input type:submit and reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close: `input[type="text"]`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYcP2/1/)

Comment: I did that, and it made the submit and reset button smaller, but the other styling I had in place for the input tag, like the shadowing and border went away.

Comment: So is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/SYcP2/2/

Comment: Basically, like that but with the submit and reset button smaller.

Comment: Ok, have you tried actually separating the styles out? Separate the css you want applied to all inputs and put it into `input {}`, then put the css you want to apply to text boxes and put it into `input[type="text"]{}`. If you need button styles, use `input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]{}`. A much better way to do this would be to use classes.

Comment: thanks for your help @brouxhaha I ended up putting the submit and reset in separate divs to separate them and then I did internal styling and it seemed to work.